# How do I convert a .csv file to a database?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, openoffice, csv

I have an 8GB .csv file with 6 columns and 202,176,000 rows. 

 How would I convert that to an OpenOffice database(.db) file?

Comment: Why is microsoft-excel tagged? This question isn't referencing excel at all.

Answer (score 0):

.db is used for several differant formats, but I'm assuming you mean Access. you can use the Access data import wizard to load the csv into a table.

Instructions here:
http://databasesuperstar.com/ms-access-tutorial-how-to-import-csv-file/

for OpenOffice, see here: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=37013

Comment: Could I use Apache Open Office Base as well?

Comment: @user3503704 [Yes](https://www.google.com/search?q=import%20csv%20to%20openoffice%20database).

Answer (score 0):

**MS Access:**

There is a tutorial at http://databasesuperstar.com/ms-access-tutorial-how-to-import-csv-file/, which is very good quality and too much to reproduce here.

---

**OpenOffice:**

From https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=37013 (source: various users), which presents multiple good options:

1. Import the CSV data into Calc. Select and copy all of the data. In the Base file, go to the Tables view (that is, click the Tables icon in the left had section), right click in the region where the tables are listed and select Paste. In the dialog that pops up, choose Definition and Data, then fill out the subsequent screens as needed. *This option copies spreadsheet data into some type of editable database (native HSQLDB, MySQL or whatever database you connect Base with).*
2. [Use the file as an editable data source](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=23260). *This option utilizes some database server's capability to load plain text into predefined tables.*
3. Store all similar csv files in one directory and connect a Base document to this directory. *This option treats a collection of plain text files as if they were tables of a read-only database. From this pseudo-database you may also copy selected data into a true database.*

See "[import csv to openoffice database](https://www.google.com/search?q=import%20csv%20to%20openoffice%20database)" for other options.

---

I have posted this as community wiki as I cannot take credit for any of the above, but am putting it here in case those other sites go down some day. Please feel free to add other options and instructions.

Comment: Open Office Calc does not take all of my data.

Comment: @user3503704 - Be specific.  You asked if it was possible.  You are already using the wrong file format for the size of data.  You should think about migrating to an actual SQL alternative.  You will have to address data type errors yourself.

Comment: @user3503704 If it is a size issue (although we don't know what "does not take all of my data" means) then you will either have to have the application that generated this data to begin with use a more appropriate format, as Ramhound just suggested, or perhaps you can manually split the file up into smaller chunks and add one at a time - exactly how you'd do that is a challenge for you to solve. OpenOffice and Access can both import CSV and the above describes how. If your particular CSV has other problems you will have to find a way to solve them.